# Как сделать автоматически обновляемый прогрессбар с заданным процентом в поле Entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, progress-bar

Как сделать автоматически обновляемый прогресс бар с заданным процентом в поле `Entry`. 
Много всего перепробовал, ничего не получилось. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я вводил процент и его сразу после ввода цифры выводило в прогресс бар, без нажатия кнопок. Только текстовое поле и прогресс бар.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()

def progres():
    pb['value'] = int(input.get())    

input = Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=(progres))
input.insert(0, 0)
input.pack()

pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode="determinate")
pb.pack()

B = ttk.Button(root, text ="Hello", command = progres)
B.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


root = Tk()
        
def validate(new_value): 
    pb['value'] = new_value if new_value else 0
    return new_value == "" or new_value.isnumeric()  

pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode="determinate")

vcmd = (root.register(validate), '%P')             
input = Entry(root, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)  

input.insert(0, 0)
input.pack()

pb.pack()

input.focus()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, работает как надо

Comment: @МаксимБеляков пожалуйста.